# ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times when check status

Tags: hbase

I am very new to Hadoop and Hbase. Now I am facing 
'ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times' when i check the status

I will attached my hbase-site.xml code bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
<property> 
        <name>hbase.master</name> 
        <value>localhost:60000</value> 
</property> 
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
</property>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/hosts` file and `/etc/hostname` file

```
127.0.0.1 hbase ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

read section 2.3(hadoop) of this site : http://hbase.eu.apache.org/book.html

Comment: Please do not use only outside links as answers; answers here should be self-contained.